# How to give comman error message instead of multiple errors in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I m new to codeigniter developement. I created simple login form as follows:

In my login_view page

```
  <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
  //my form html code comes here
```

In my controller page

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
  $this->load->view('login_view',$data);
}
else
{
 //form validated do some work here
}
```

Now problem is that when I submit form with empty username and password field this shows me errors as

```
The Username field is required.
The Password field is required.
```

This is right but I want to show only single message as

```
Please enter username and password......
```

instead of two or N number of messages per field. I already tried form_error('fieldname') function but no use. How do I get above mentioned output.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the view you can use:

```
<?php if (form_error('username') || form_error('password')): ?>
  <div class="error">Please enter username and password......</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```